# JEditorpane cannot load URL

Tags: java, url, jeditorpane

I have problem with my JEditorPane, cannot load URL, always show java.io.FileNotFoundException. Totally I am confused how to solve it.

```
JEditorPane editorpane = new JEditorPane();
            editorpane.setEditable(false);
            String backslash="\\";
            String itemcode="a91000mf";
            int ctr=6;
            File file = new File("file:///C:/Development/project2/OfflineSales/test/index.html?item_code="+itemcode+"&jumlah="+String.valueOf(ctr)+"&lokasi=../images");
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    //editorpane.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener)
                    editorpane.setPage(file.toURL());
                    System.out.println(file.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.toString());
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("Couldn't find file: TextSamplerDemoHelp.html");
            }
```

I just put `"file:///C:/Development/project2/OfflineSales/test/index.html?item_code="+itemcode"`, but it will show its same error : cannot open file, but I can open it in my browser

Comment: try using this:
`File file = new File("/Development/project2/OfflineSales/test/index.html?item_code="+itemcode"");`

Answer (score 0):

`File` expects a local file path, but "file://...." is a URI... so try this:

```
URI uri = new URI("file:///C:/Development/project2/OfflineSales/test/index.html?item_code="+itemcode+"&jumlah="+String.valueOf(ctr)+"&lokasi=../images");
File file = new File(uri);
```

Comment: it will show Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component

Comment: Ahhh, sounds like you're running a local web server... in that case use the `http://` prefix and base it off of your webserver's root (instead of using `file://`).

Comment: i try to load local file html with its css

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all usage of the File class.

A string which starts with "file:" is a URL, not a file name. It is not a valid argument to a File constructor.

You are calling the [JEditor.setPage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setPage-java.net.URL-) method which takes a URL, not a File.  There is no reason to create a File instance:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("file:///C:/Development/project2/OfflineSales/test/index.html?item_code=" + itemcode + "&jumlah=" + ctr + "&lokasi=../images");
    editorpane.setPage(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

JEditorPane also has a convenience method which does the conversion of a String into a URL for you, so you can even skip the use of the URL class entirely:

```
String url = "file:///C:/Development/project2/OfflineSales/test/index.html?item_code=" + itemcode + "&jumlah=" + ctr + "&lokasi=../images";
try {
    editorpane.setPage(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(Notice that `String.valueOf` is not needed.  It is implicitly invoked whenever you concatenate a String with any object or primitive value.)